# Writing a function that inputs arguments into a vector of std::bind objects

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I want to store a vector of actions which can apply to any class that has a specific signature (in this test case, takes an integer and double as input).  I've coded this successfully with std::function and std::bind.

Now, I want to create a function in which I can pass the inputs to and have it call the push_back.  I can't seem to figure out how to write this function (namely, the signatures of its arguments).  Pored through stackoverflow for awhile; can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct TestA
{
    void regular(int64_t a, double b)
    {
        std::cout << "TestA::regular(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};
struct TestB
{
    void alternate(int64_t a, double b)
    {
        std::cout << "TestB::alternate(" << a << "," << b << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TestA a;
    TestB b;

    std::vector< std::function<void(int64_t, double)> > vec;
    vec.push_back( std::bind(&TestA::regular, &a, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2) );
    vec.push_back( std::bind(&TestB::alternate, &b, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2) );
    // thisIsTheFunctionIWantToWrite(vec, &TestA::regular, &a);

    for(auto f: vec)
        f(1,2.3);
}
```

I want the function thisIsTheFunctionIWantToWrite to execute the following (though I can't figure out what to put for HELP):

```
void thisIsTheFunctionIWantToWrite(std::vector< std::function<void(int64_t, double)> >& vec, HELP x, HELP y){
    vec.push_back( std::bind(x, y, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2) );
}
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, you can just use lambda function:  ` vec.push_back( [](int64_t a, double b){std::cout << "Test" << a << ","<< b << std::endl;});`

Comment: `template <typename X, typename Y> void thisIsTheFunctionIWantToWrite(..., X x, Y y);`